# PDF output in PHP contains html header and footer section. How to delete it?

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf

I have a web page which is generated as follows:

```
include('header.inc.php');
include('content.php');
include('footer.inc.php');
```

Within **content.php** I evoke headers to automatically download a PDF file:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="myFile.pdf"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

$myFile = "/var/www/.../pdf/myFile.pdf"
readfile($myFile);
```

The PDF is generated but also contains all content from header and footer.

```
header:
<Doctype...>
<html>
...
<body>

footer:
<script ...>
...
</body>
</html>
```

How do I remove all the html code from the PDF?

I tried to remove all html from the document via jQuery but it takes no effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).html('').append(<?=readfile($myFile)?>);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to build html headers to include a pdf file in your page. Instead of using php to do that, you can simply create your own html to embed the pdf in your page. Embed will do the same thing you are trying to do but this way you will generate your own html without using php :

```
<html><body><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="link to your pdf goes here" type="application/pdf"></body></html>
```

Comment: I would like to achieve that my PDF files does not contain the whole content from my webpage, e.g. html header, html images, html titles, html div-content,..., html footer + pdf image content but only the pdf image content.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

Store the filename in a variable and replace:

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="myFile.pdf"');
```

with:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```